# C# Font class design

Tags: c#, .net, font-size

Why there are no setters in Font class in .NET?

It would be so much better to be able to decrease/increase font size by simply aplying increment operators for instance font.Size++

But instead of this everytime I want to change font size or style or whatever, I have to create a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Font` class is a GDI+ wrapper.  GDI+ objects don't have such operations, and thus doesn't the class `Font`.

You can get some knowledge here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534437(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Comparisons to GDI objects aren't relevant -- this is GDI+, not GDI; it's a fundamentally different library. But yes, the GDI+ Font class is immutable.

Comment: Why they use these obsolete classes in my brand new .Net 4.0 ?

Comment: @Ask they're not obsolete, they are the way WINDOWS does FONTS.  It's like you say that PIXEL is obsolete and it should be replaced :)

Comment: They could write a better wrapper which implements increment operators and allows you to make your font Bold simply by setting Bold=true.

Comment: @Ask well, it seems that you found yourself a nice little task :)  Why don't you try it?

Comment: I'm just wondering what was the problem to implement this behavior in .NET. They have so much syntax sugar, but simple things sometimes poorly implemented.